# Update Table contents from another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, xml

I want to update the products table from my store db from a temp table.. the production table 'Products' needs to update all columns from the temp table 'tmpprod' based on StockCode and not change any other columns in the Products table

```
UPDATE Products
JOIN tmpprod
ON Products.StockCode = tmpprod.StockCode
    SET Products.CategoryCode = tmpprod.CategoryCode,
        Products.CategoryName = tmpprod.CategoryName,
        Products.SubcategoryID = tmpprod.SubcategoryID,
        Products.SubcategoryName = tmpprod.SubcategoryName,
        Products.BarCode = tmpprod.BarCode,
        Products.Weight = tmpprod.Weight,
        Products.ManufacturerSKU = tmpprod.ManufacturerSKU,
        Products.ProductName = tmpprod.ProductName,
        Products.WarrantyLength = tmpprod.WarrantyLength,
        Products.Manufacturer = tmpprod.Manufacturer,
        Products.DBP = tmpprod.DBP,
        Products.DBP5 = tmpprod.DBP5,
        Products.RRP = tmpprod.RRP,
        Products.StandardRRP = tmpprod.StandardRRP,
        Products.AvailabilityTotal = tmpprod.AvailabilityTotal,
        Products.AvailabilityAdelaide = tmpprod.AvailabilityAdelaide,
        Products.AvailabilityBrisbane = tmpprod.AvailabilityBrisbane,
        Products.AvailabilitySydney = tmpprod.AvailabilitySydney,
        Products.AvailabilityMelbourne = tmpprod.AvailabilityMelbourne,
        Products.AvailabilityPerth = tmpprod.AvailabilityPerth,
        Products.ImageUrl = tmpprod.ImageUrl,
        Products.ImageFilename = tmpprod.ImageFilename,
        Products.DescriptionLink = tmpprod.DescriptionLink
```

and...

```
CREATE TABLE `Products` (
    `StockCode` text, 
    `CategoryCode` text, 
    `CategoryName` text, 
    `SubcategoryID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `SubcategoryName` text, 
    `BarCode` text, 
    `Weight` double DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ManufacturerSKU` text, 
    `ProductName` text, 
    `WarrantyLength` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `Manufacturer` text, 
    `DBP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `DBP5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `RRP` double DEFAULT NULL, 
    `StandardRRP` double DEFAULT NULL, 
    `AvailabilityTotal` text, 
    `AvailabilityAdelaide` text, 
    `AvailabilityBrisbane` text, 
    `AvailabilitySydney` text, 
    `AvailabilityMelbourne` text, 
    `AvailabilityPerth` text, 
    `ImageUrl` text, 
    `WebsiteUrl` text, 
    `ImageFilename` text, 
    `DescriptionLink` text, 
    `DateAdded` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    `ForSale` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

and...

```
'CREATE TABLE `tmpprod` (
    `StockCode` text,
    `CategoryCode` text,
    `CategoryName` text,
    `SubcategoryID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `SubcategoryName` text, 
    `BarCode` text, 
    `Weight` double DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ManufacturerSKU` text, 
    `ProductName` text, 
    `WarrantyLength` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `Manufacturer` text, 
    `DBP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `DBP5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `RRP` double DEFAULT NULL, 
    `StandardRRP` double DEFAULT NULL, 
    `AvailabilityTotal` text, 
    `AvailabilityAdelaide` text, 
    `AvailabilityBrisbane` text, 
    `AvailabilitySydney` text, 
    `AvailabilityMelbourne` text, 
    `AvailabilityPerth` text, 
    `ImageUrl` text, 
    `WebsiteUrl` text, 
    `ImageFilename` text, 
    `DescriptionLink` text, 
    `DateAdded` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Comment: The code you posted seems to work. I am unsure what you are asking.

Comment: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: if i turn this off in workbench and run the query it just hangs :(

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; we need to see the KEYs.

Comment: @RickJames  ive added those into the original code quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB really needs a `PRIMARY KEY` on each table.  You must add it to the real table; it is less important for the temp table.

Don't blindly use `TEXT` for every column; use things like `VARCHAR(10)` or `VARCHAR(100)`.  The codes and skus probably have known max length.  Names rarely get over `(60)`.  Etc.  Use `TEXT` only for really long strings.

If "Availability" is a true/false flag, use `TINYINT`.

Now for the real problem -- How does `UPDATE` know which row to change??  Do you have some column (or columns) that uniquely identifies the row so that you clobber the correct one?  That should be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Without the index, it is scanning the entire table repeatedly.  Very slow.

Comment: Thank you soo much for that silly me just let the xml importer create the table itself just ran it again with decent data types and some duplicate handling processes and it works beautifully  0.341s to verify and update 6000 rows :D

Comment: I often ask for `CREATE TABLE`, especially when there is no obvious answer to a Question.  This case was quite a surprise, and made it easy to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Postgres docs (9.6)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

```
UPDATE Products as P
SET P.CategoryCode = T.CategoryCode,
    P.CategoryName = T.CategoryName,
    P.SubcategoryID = T.SubcategoryID,
    P.SubcategoryName = T.SubcategoryName,
    P.BarCode = T.BarCode,
    P.Weight = T.Weight,
    P.ManufacturerSKU = T.ManufacturerSKU,
    P.ProductName = T.ProductName,
    P.WarrantyLength = T.WarrantyLength,
    P.Manufacturer = T.Manufacturer,
    P.DBP = T.DBP,
    P.DBP5 = T.DBP5,
    P.RRP = T.RRP,
    P.StandardRRP = T.StandardRRP,
    P.AvailabilityTotal = T.AvailabilityTotal,
    P.AvailabilityAdelaide = T.AvailabilityAdelaide,
    P.AvailabilityBrisbane = T.AvailabilityBrisbane,
    P.AvailabilitySydney = T.AvailabilitySydney,
    P.AvailabilityMelbourne = T.AvailabilityMelbourne,
    P.AvailabilityPerth = T.AvailabilityPerth,
    P.ImageUrl = T.ImageUrl,
    P.ImageFilename = T.ImageFilename,
    P.DescriptionLink = T.DescriptionLink
FROM tmpprod as T
WHERE P.StockCode = T.StockCode;
```

Although I used an alias, it is not indispensable.